# permanent NAS-mount in Ubuntu - wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: ubuntu, mount, network-attached-storage, network-share, server-message-block

My network drive shows up in the file browser, just like my external usb-harddrive. Moving, running and editing files works. Hovering over it shows smb://lacie-2big/nasdisk .

BUT, when I want to save a file, the drive doesn't come up as an option. All I can see is my other places, including my usb-harddrive.

I am a complete newbie but I am GUESSING that it has something to do with the mount not being a "real" mount but just a shortcut to the smb location.

So I ran the tutorial at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently about how to "mount a network drive permanently".

edited my fstab to

//LaCie-2big/nasdisk  /media/nasmount  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0

and running sudo mount -a gave me the following error:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //LaCie-2big/nasdisk,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Now thats a very helpful error message, BUT, before I go any further, I'd be really thankful if one of you could tell me if I'm even in the right ballpark, or if my actual need: to be able to download files (ie torrents) directly to the drive, can be possible as it is already.

**Question: How to fix "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //LaCie-2big/nasdisk,
       missing codepage or helper program" when running mount -a**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.

Try without the codepage stuff, ( take out iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode ).
verify mount.cifs exist by running which mount.cifs as root.

Does the end of the output of dmesg show anything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Running mount -a now gives me: "error, could not resolve adress for LaCie-2big". I edited the fstab to have the path smb://lacie-2big/nasdisk instead, but that gave me the error "Mounting cifs url not implemented yet. Attempt to mount smb://lacie-2big/nasdisk

Comment: Ah, solved it now. I just replaced the lacie-2big part with the actual IP adress of the NAS and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if `mount.cifs` exists as a command. If it doesn't, run `apt-get install cifs-utils`. Part of this package is the mount.cifs helper program that fstab uses.